# Boost Random Generators returning identical values

Tags: c++, random, boost, c++98

WITHOUT USING C++ 11 RANDOM

Looking for a boost random expert... I need to generate random numbers in between many, many different ranges.  I've written the below functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/generator_iterator.hpp>

boost::mt19937 g_oRng;

int generateIntVariate(int p_iMin, int p_iMax){
  boost::uniform_int<> min_to_max(p_iMin, p_iMax);
  boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_int<> > oGen(g_oRng, min_to_max);
  return oGen();
}

float generateFloatVariate(int p_fMin, p_fMax){
  boost::uniform_real<> min_to_max(p_fMin, p_fMax);
  boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_real<> > oGen(m_oRng, min_to_max);
  return oGen();
}


int main(){
  struct timeval tp;
  gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
  g_oRng = boost::mt19937((int)tp.tv_sec);


  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i){
    std::cout << generateIntVariate(0, 10) << ", " << generateFloatVariate(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The problem is that both functions return the same exact number for a given range, every time it's executed.

```
(gdb) p generateIntVariate(0, 10)
$40 = 8
(gdb) p generateIntVariate(0, 10)
$41 = 8
(gdb) p generateIntVariate(0, 10)
$42 = 8
(gdb) p generateIntVariate(0, 10)
$43 = 8
```

The same thing as above happens with the float function.  Is there any way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do using the boost random distros?

Comment: plus1 to counter the anonymous neg1

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?  Right from the start I see your not seeding the PRNG so you will always get the same sequence.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am actually, it's just not shown here. I seed it with gettimeofday's tv_sec

Comment: note that there's no need to use boost here, C++ bascially has exactly the same random functions

Comment: @TheTechel not if you don't have access to C++ 11

Comment: I don't know why there are close votes, I cannot use <random> - no C++11 compiler

Comment: Because we need a [mcve].  Give use code that compiles so we can see what it is specifically doing.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is exactly what this is. This is the only code being executed, and there is sample input and output.

Comment: Can't be.  You mention your using a constructor so you have at least one object being created somewhere and your using it.  Why is it so difficult to give us something that compiles?

Comment: Hardly a complete example without `int main()`. We can''t compile and run this.

Comment: @JesperJuhl added

Comment: @Riptyde4 Still waiting for you to fix the missing parameter type and missing `:` in `boost:mt19937`. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`boost::variate_generator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/variate_generator.html)'s constructor looks like this:

```
variate_generator(Engine e, Distribution d);
```

- meaning it won't change the state of passed-in `m_oRng` and makes a copy of it instead.

I suggest omitting `variate_generator` and just using `boost::uniform_int<>::operator()`.